# Why these:margin, padding, box-sizing, text-decoration, border, scroll-behaviour, font-famil have no value in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So here is the Pastebin. Now I am trying to make my own website and I have been watching tutorial for that...but in one of the videos the guy types these into the style.css file he has created and they have value in there but I have no returned value to these... I am also quite new to front-end developing and I understand that my question is probably not properly structured. The tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tkp3FDgOueM on 6:16

I will also post my HTML file here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="bg">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheets" href="css/style1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header"></header>
 <a href="#" class="logo">Портфолио</a>
 
 <nav class="navbar">
      <a href ="#ние">Ние><a>
      <a href ="#услуги">Услуги><a>
      <a href ="проекти">Проекти<a>
      <a href ="отзиви">Отзиви<a></a>
</nav>
   <!--custom js-->>
   <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Style CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    scroll-behaviour: smooth;
    font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
}
```

Thanks!

I've looked more carefully but saw nothing wrong with mine and his code.

Comment: "_but I have no returned value to these_" what do you mean by that? I don't understand.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

to apply your style you need a css selector, try add body as a selector as below.

```
body{
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        scroll-behaviour: smooth;
        font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed guys. I had to add * at the beginning of the code.
Thank you.